# PowerShell 5 REST request response is a string instead of JSON object

Tags: json, powershell, object, type-conversion

So, I am making a `GET` request to a REST endpoint. The response I get back is in fact an object, however, the subcategory of `Content` and then from inside that as well, `data` are both `String` types. How do I make sure the entire response is formatted as an object? Otherwise I can't actually do anything with this data.

I have tried converting from string to object, but nothing seems to work. Very new to PS though, so I'm sure I am missing something here.

Comment: you might want to use `Invoke-RestMethod` when working with a REST endpoint (as it converts JSON for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet.

For example:

```
$obj = ConvertFrom-Json $response.data;
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Like I said, still learning this new language. Much appreciated Jon!!